# String format doesn't handle correctly rounded Numpy Float32?

Tags: python, numpy

I accidentally came into this weird behavior when use format string together with Numpy 32 float and Numpy.round() . To reproduce:

```py
score=0.7827188774

npf32_score_rounded=np.round(np.float32(0.7827188774),4)
score_rounded=np.round(score,4)

print(f" {npf32_score_rounded}")
print(f" {score_rounded}")

print(npf32_score_rounded)
print(score_rounded)

#0.7827000021934509 expect to get 0.7827
#0.7827
#0.7827 # without string format, it works as expected
#0.7827
```

Is this behavior normal or it should be fixed?

Numpy version == 1.20.2

Python version == 3.8.0

Comment: It is really strange, because ```np.round(a, decimals)``` method is the same as ```np.true_divide(np.rint(a * 10**decimals), 10**decimals)``` for positive ```decimals```. And the second one works as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's f-strings call the objects `__format__` function. As can be seen in [numpy's source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L273), for a floating point number this does a conversion to a Python `float` (64bit) before.

---

Since the value stored in the 32 bit float actually is `0.782700002193450927734375` (see [IEE 754](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)) for Python's higher precision `float` these decimal places are now significant. That's why those decimal places are now printed. Thanks [@user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) for pointing this out.

So it is the expected result.

---

```py
import numpy as np

val = 0.7827188774

np_float_32 = np.round(np.float32(val), 4)
assert type(np_float_32) == np.float32

np_float_64 = np.round(val, 4)
assert type(np_float_64) == np.float64

# just calling print, no issues
print(np_float_32, np_float_64) # 0.7827 0.7827

# both str and repr work as intended
print(str(np_float_32), str(np_float_64)) # 0.7827 0.7827
print(repr(np_float_32), repr(np_float_64)) # 0.7827 0.7827

# behavior described by OP
print(f'{np_float_32} {np_float_64}') # 0.7827000021934509 0.7827

# f-string without format specification calls obj.__format__('')
# see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L273
# explicit conversion to python float
print(float(np_float_32), float(np_float_64)) # 0.7827000021934509 0.7827
```

Comment: The conversion isn't losing precision - NumPy float32 to Python float is an exact conversion. The problem is that `float.__format__` is designed to format a 64-bit value, and its idea of what digits are significant is based on the assumption of a 64-bit float instead of a 32-bit float.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Will update the answer accordingly